# Threadsafe over Bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety

Can anyone tell me why this code is wrong and how I have to modify it in order to create a simple Bitmap of which is guranteed thread-safe access?

```
public static class ThreadSafe
{
    public static readonly object _locker = new object();
    public static Bitmap _snapshot;

    public static Bitmap Snapshot
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                return _snapshot;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                _snapshot = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT** How I want use that Bitmap:

- Thread A use the Bitmap in this way:

> new Bitmap(ThreadSafe.Snapshot, new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240));

- Thread B uses the Bitmap in this way:

> ThreadSafe.Snapshot = new Bitmap(target, new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240));

Comment: [You're going to need to be much more specific about what you mean by thread safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx).  There are all sorts of things that you may want to do, and you need to handle them specifically.

Comment: I want that more then one thread can access the Bitmap.

Comment: Again, you're going to need to be *far* more specific than that.

Comment: When you get an object, you get a reference to the object. When you access the reference from multiple threads and change it you are changing the object you got without locking.

Comment: The only operations I need to do are get or set that Bitmap

Comment: @Joseph82 If all you want to do is get the bitmap *and then never ever do anything with it, ever*.  Then sure.  This is safe already.  If you ever want to do anything with it at all, then you're going to need to explain what, so we can help you go about doing that.  Without knowing what you want to do, the answer is that it's not possible.

Comment: for example, what if a caller calls `ThreadSafe.Snapshot.Dispose()`?

Comment: @Servy I've edited my question in order to answer your question about the use of my Bitmap

Comment: Thank you @JoachimIsaksson, so how  can I change my code for make that  Bitmap thread-safe?

Comment: I'd put both operations in the class and lock fully around the entire ThreadA operation and the same lock around ThreadB's changing the reference. Make the bitmap field private so no one else can muck with it. I'd answer with code if I weren't on an iPhone ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the thread safety guidelines from the [Bitmap documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

...this should be close to the minimum locking implementation;

```
public static class ThreadSafe
{
    private static readonly object BitmapLock = new object();
    private static Bitmap _snapshot;

    public static Bitmap Snapshot
    {
        get
        {
            lock (BitmapLock)
                return new Bitmap(_snapshot);
        }
        set
        {
            Bitmap oldSnapshot;
            Bitmap newSnapshot = new Bitmap(value, new Size(320, 240));
            lock (BitmapLock) 
            {
                oldSnapshot = _snapshot;
                _snapshot = newSnapshot;
            }
            if (oldSnapshot != null)
                oldSnapshot.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But how can I take care of disposing the old Bitmap when a new one is assigned to snapshot var, using the set method?

Comment: @Joseph82 Too little coffee apparently, added the needed Dispose() call.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just another question. If I call `using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height)){ThreadSafe.Snapshot = new Bitmap(target, new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240));}`. I need to Dispose also the last created Bitmap or this Bitmap is Dispose inside the `set`?

Comment: Or I can simple call  `using (Bitmap target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height)){ /*some stuff here*/ ThreadSafe.Snapshot = target; }` ?

Answer (score 1):

If these are the only 2 things that you do with the bitmap:

```
new Bitmap(ThreadSafe.Snapshot, new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240));
ThreadSafe.Snapshot = new Bitmap(target, new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240));
```

Then congratulations, you are threadsafe already without any need for extra work at all (just add `volatile`):

```
public static class ThreadSafe
{
    public static volatile Bitmap Snapshot;
}
```

Comment: It would need to be violate.

Comment: @Servy - Well... I guess it won't hurt, though I think it wouldn't matter if it wasn't there either.

Comment: It would in that one thread can end up accessing a cached value of the variable, or only setting a cached value.  Different threads can end up not seeing updates from the other threads.

Comment: Until the cache entry ends up being invalidated.  If the working set of memory is smaller than the cache (which is very often the case), that could end up being quite a long time.

Comment: I don't think using a shared instance as source of the constructor is strictly safe (or at least it's documented as no instance methods, even read operations, on a shared instance is safe.)

Comment: MS doesn't really bother to *actually* document whether any given operation is thread safe or not.  Outside of a handful of classes specifically designed for concurrent access (namely what's in the system.collections.concurrent) they just punt and say, "it may or may not be safe, we won't *guarantee* it, but it may still be.  In reality, reading from most anything that's not being concurrently mutated is safe.  I couldn't imagine how reading out the data of a `Bitmap` would mutate it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, with a dispose implementation for the snapshot copy:

```
public static class ThreadSafe
{
    private static readonly object _locker = new object();
    private static Bitmap _snapshot;

    public static Bitmap GetSnapshot(int width, int height)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_snapshot == null)
                return null;

            return new Bitmap(_snapshot, new Size(width, height));
        }
    }

    public static void SetSnapshot(Bitmap source, int width, int height)
    {
        var copy = new Bitmap(source, new Size(width, height));
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_snapshot != null)
                _snapshot.Dispose();
            _snapshot = copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Kudos for the `Dispose()`! Btw - maybe use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`? That could get a better performance, I think.

Comment: This is not entirely safe, depending on how it's used.  A caller can call `SetSnapshot` and then the `Bitmap` can end up being mutated from another thread that has a reference to it while this method is in the process of copying it to a new `Bitmap`.  That could cause all sorts of possible problems.

Comment: also, the `lock` accomplishes nothing here beyond a memory barrier when accessing `_snapshot`, which would be handled simply by making it `volatile`, yet it slows down the whole application.  Copying the image isn't very fast, yet you don't allow any of the copies to take place concurrently, neither on the reading or the writing site, when there's no reason to prohibit it.

Comment: Also, because you leave `_snapshot` public it can be messed with by other threads without going through these methods, which can cause all sorts of problems, the most straightforward of which is mutating it while a copy is being made of it.

Comment: @Servy True, the _snapshot should have been private. Fixed that. I think a lock is better over volatile since I go beyond assignments only. Also, check this MSDN article about volatile vs locks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863136.aspx

Comment: A ReaderWriterLockSlim could improve performance as @Vilx suggested.

Comment: But it's *not* better because everything that you do beyond getting/setting the field *doesn't need to be synchronized*.  There is no reason for `GetShapshot` to hold up another call to `GetSnapshot` because it's copying the image.  There's no reason for `SetSnapshot` to hold up a read either.  Since reference assignments are atomic the read will either get the new image, or the old image, but either way it will be entirely valid.  There's no reason to stop reads while copying the image to be set over, or vice versa.

Comment: @MarkO You can just remove the `lock` entirely.  There is no synchronization needed here at all, whether it be a full `lock` or a read/write lock.  *None* is providing any additional safety.  They are only ever slowing things down.

Comment: Well, I moved the copy out of the lock in the Set, but in the get I think it needs to be there. Otherwise a copy can be disrupted by a Dispose through another threads Set.

Comment: Then you're still blocking concurrent reads, and when reading is an expensive operation, that's still a problem.  And it's still not entirely safe, [as I described earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229702/threadsafe-over-bitmap-in-c-sharp/22230358?noredirect=1#comment33755673_22230447)

Comment: The source Bitmap is owned by the caller thread, so no other thread should have a reference to it. If any does, then we indeed have a problem, but that is IMHO out of scope for this snapshot implementation. Yes threads are blocked, but not Disposing snapshots by overriding the reference is no solution either.

Comment: @MarkO You can use a read/write lock at that point, given that "writing" is only disposing and setting a reference, rather than needing to do a copy.  At that point you've now reduced any blocking on synchronization down to very minimal levels.