# Access Violation Exception in System.Drawing.dll when saving jpeg

Tags: c#

I have a camera which uses Emgucv Package to take photo in some parts of my code.
I randomly get AccessViolationException in System.Drawing.dll when trying to save a Jpeg file. As a result I have a corrupted Jpeg file.

My code is run on windows 10 and is written in Microsoft visual studio 2015.

This is my code that throws an exception randomly:

```
    public Boolean SavePhoto(Bitmap image)
    {try
        {
            MyGate.LogCamera("Start Save Photo");

            string photoTime = PersianDateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + "_"
              + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

            String photoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.UserImagePath , PersianDateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(photoPath)==false)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(photoPath);
            }

            photoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(photoPath, photoTime + ".jpg");
            MyGate.LogCamera("Just Before Save Photo");
            SaveJpeg(photoPath, image, 90);
            MyGate.LogCamera("End Save Photo");
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            new NDCBaseClass().LogError(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }

    }

    public  void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img, int quality)
    {
        try
        {
            // Encoder parameter for image quality 
            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new     EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
            // JPEG image codec 
            ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            new NDCBaseClass().LogError(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: My best guess, with the limited code you have shown, is that multiple threads are calling `SaveJpeg` with the same `Image` at the same time. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22232639/34092

Comment: If it is really random, you could try catching the exception, and they retrying the save until it works, but I agree with the other comments, that it does sound like a threading issue.

Comment: My code is a part of a large application and it is difficult for me to provide more complete one. The function calls when I take photo and the app is not multi thread. I take photo when users enter PIN, therefore it is not one image. For example it might take 10 photos of different users and suddenly throws exception for the next one.

Comment: `My code is a part of a large application and it is difficult for me to provide more complete one.` If it is difficult to work out what is happening, and you have access to the source code - imagine how hard it is for us! Note also that at least 90% of the reason we ask for you to create a [mcve] is that the mere act of you **trying to create it** you will solve your issue. It forces you to breakdown the problem.

Comment: `For example it might take 10 photos of different users and suddenly throws exception for the next one.` My guess is you aren't disposing of one of your image's properly, and thus running out of RAM or handles.

Comment: That is not yet a [mcve]. When I can copy and paste it into a console app and run it - you are done. This isn't one, since I need to see how `SavePhoto` is being called. **Note that your [mcve] must reproduce the same issue as your post talks about - don't make it so minimal that the bug doesn't occur!**

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

calling GC.Collect after img.save method solves the problem.